# MVC C# Application _Layout page suddenly converted to... hex page?

Tags: c#

I was working on my application when I suddenly lost power on my pc. Turned it back on, however two of my pages layout(MOST IMPORTANT) and a random index page is appearing to be in what seems like hex characters to me. Also typing on the keyboard creates those same characters.

Is there  probably an option for this or to revert this? I would hate losing my layout file.
[image]

Comment: you do use source control, right?

Comment: There's some suggestions here - https://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/11/30/visual-studio-crashes-and-a-corrupted-cs-file/